# Array prints the same object n times

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, for-loop, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb query, then I use a for to loop the result and pushes some items into new array. But the output shows the same object n times.

The if statements are fine and the query is ok too, the problem comes in the push to closedTickets, I print the object to push, and then push it but I'm getting that weird behavior.
I tried with a hashmap using the _id as key and if the map doesn't have the key then set the object, but didn't worked, please help me.

Code:

```
    const ticketsQuery = await Action.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdTime: { $gte: new Date(from), $lte: new Date(to) },
        action: { $in: ['open', 'hold', 'pending', 'closed']}
      }
    }, {
      $group: {
        _id: '$task',
        actions: {
          $push: {
            action: '$action',
            date: '$createdTime'
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tasks',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'task',
      }
    }, {
      $match: {
        'task.organization': orgID
      }
    }
  ]);

  const ticket = {}
  const closedTickets = [];

  for (const ticketsQueryElement of ticketsQuery) {
    ticket.closedAt = 0;
    ticket.openAt = 0;
    ticket.holdAt = 0;
    ticket.pendingAt = 0;
    ticket.task = ticketsQueryElement._id
    for (const closedTicket of ticketsQueryElement.actions) {
        if (closedTicket.action === 'open') {
          if (ticket.openAt === 0) {
            ticket.openAt = closedTicket.date;
          } else if (ticket.openAt < closedTicket.date) {
            ticket.openAt = closedTicket.date;
          }
        }
        if (closedTicket.action === 'hold') {
          if (ticket.holdAt === 0) {
            ticket.holdAt = closedTicket.date;
          } else if (ticket.holdAt < closedTicket.date) {
            ticket.holdAt = closedTicket.date;
          }
        }
        if (closedTicket.action === 'pending') {
          if (ticket.pendingAt === 0) {
            ticket.pendingAt = closedTicket.date;
          } else if (ticket.pendingAt < closedTicket.date) {
            ticket.pendingAt = closedTicket.date;
          }
        }
        if (closedTicket.action === 'closed') {
          if (ticket.closedAt === 0) {
            ticket.closedAt = closedTicket.date;
          } else if (ticket.closedAt < closedTicket.date) {
            ticket.closedAt = closedTicket.date;
          }
        }

    }
    if ((ticket.openAt !== 0 || ticket.holdAt !== 0
      || ticket.pendingAt !== 0) && ticket.closedAt !== 0) {
      // output 1
      console.log(ticket)
      closedTickets.push(ticket);
    }
  }

  // output 2
  console.log(closedTickets)
```

And the outputs show this:

output 1:

```
{
  closedAt: 2019-11-12T20:02:38.897Z,
  openAt: 2019-11-11T18:04:10.296Z,
  holdAt: 0,
  pendingAt: 0,
  task: 5dc6f9fad550ac3c68d8bcd3
}
{
  closedAt: 2019-11-08T20:03:22.833Z,
  openAt: 2019-11-07T17:08:10.769Z,
  holdAt: 0,
  pendingAt: 0,
  task: 5dc37d03d550ac3c68d8aed6
}
{
  closedAt: 2019-11-13T00:03:27.695Z,
  openAt: 2019-11-11T20:08:10.305Z,
  holdAt: 0,
  pendingAt: 0,
  task: 5dc9bdcb44386e3c697d61c9
}
```

output 2:

```
[
  {
    closedAt: 2019-11-08T17:03:54.984Z,
    openAt: 2019-11-07T16:03:06.234Z,
    holdAt: 0,
    pendingAt: 0,
    task: 5dc377638d25253b5cbaa5d4
  },
  {
    closedAt: 2019-11-08T17:03:54.984Z,
    openAt: 2019-11-07T16:03:06.234Z,
    holdAt: 0,
    pendingAt: 0,
    task: 5dc377638d25253b5cbaa5d4
  },
  {
    closedAt: 2019-11-08T17:03:54.984Z,
    openAt: 2019-11-07T16:03:06.234Z,
    holdAt: 0,
    pendingAt: 0,
    task: 5dc377638d25253b5cbaa5d4
  }
]
```

Comment: You have to initialize `ticket = {}` **inside** the loop.

Comment: To elaborate on @Pointy's point, each time the OP code pushes `ticket` onto the array, it is pushing a reference to the *same object*, the one created by the literal before the loop.  `ticket = {}` inside the loop creates a new object on each iteration.

Comment: @danh that is correct, I was looking for a duplicate because there are hundreds if not thousands; it's an easy mistake to make. (I'm terrible at finding duplicates.)